# Duplicate code in if then ... else statement

Tags: vba, excel

I intend to perform two actions by clicking a button. let's say Action A and Action B. Following is the code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
  If "Condition A" Then
    "Action A"
    "Action B"
  Else
    "Action B"
  End If
```

In my code, the Action B part is duplicated before and after "Else" statement. I am wondering if there is a way to make the code slimmer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
If "Condition A" Then
   "Action A"
End If

"Action B" ' <-- take this outside the If
```

Comment: Thanks! It works. I've realized that it's such a simple question.